# Cannot hide action bar inside fragment using event listener

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am beginner to Android development. I just started learning Android Development. Now I am trying to hide action bar from fragment. But it is throwing error. It is throwing null exception.

What is wrong with my code ?

This is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ObjectDrawerItem[] drawerItem = new ObjectDrawerItem[3];

        drawerItem[0] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.icon_1, "Create");
        drawerItem[1] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.icon_2, "Read");
        drawerItem[2] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.icon_3, "Help");
        DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, drawerItem);

        mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),view.getTag().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            selectItem(position);
        }

    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = null;//fragment for position zero
               // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"position 0",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = null;
               // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"position 1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = null;
               // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"position 2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        fragment = new TestFragment();
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

          //  mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
          //  mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
           // getActionBar().setTitle("Title changed");
           // mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Error in creating fragment",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my fragment class:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button hideActionBarBtn;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment,container,false);
        hideActionBarBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_hide_action_bar);
        hideActionBarBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"Hide action bar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

This is my testing code for learning android. When I call this method to hide action bar, it is throwing error:

```
getActivity().getActionBar().hide().
```

Why? Is it correct way to do it? I am very new to android.

This is what I got in logcat:

> 01-18 00:49:33.475 12614-12614/com.example.navigationdrawerbegin.navigationdrawerbegin W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6176908) 01-18 00:49:33.479 12614-12614/com.example.navigationdrawerbegin.navigationdrawerbegin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 01-18 00:49:33.479 12614-12614/com.example.navigationdrawerbegin.navigationdrawerbegin E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException 01-18 00:49:33.479 12614-12614/com.example.navigationdrawerbegin.navigationdrawerbegin E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.navigationdrawerbegin.navigationdrawerbegin.TestFragment.onClick(TestFragment.java:32) 01-18 00:49:33.479 12614-12614/com.example.navigationdrawerbegin.navigationdrawerbegin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 01-18 00:49:33.479 12614-12614/com.example.navigationdrawerbegin.navigationdrawerbegin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) 01-18 00:49:33.479 12614-12614/com.example.navigationdrawerbegin.navigationdrawerbegin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 01-18 00:49:33.479 12614-12614/com.example.navigationdrawerbegin.navigationdrawerbegin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 01-18 00:49:33.479 12614-12614/com.example.navigationdrawerbegin.navigationdrawerbegin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 01-18 00:49:33.479 12614-12614/com.example.navigationdrawerbegin.navigationdrawerbegin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 01-18 00:49:33.479 12614-12614/com.example.navigationdrawerbegin.navigationdrawerbegin E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-18 00:49:33.479 12614-12614/com.example.navigationdrawerbegin.navigationdrawerbegin E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 01-18 00:49:33.479 12614-12614/com.example.navigationdrawerbegin.navigationdrawerbegin E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 01-18 00:49:33.479 12614-12614/com.example.navigationdrawerbegin.navigationdrawerbegin E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 01-18 00:49:33.479 12614-12614/com.example.navigationdrawerbegin.navigationdrawerbegin E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: It seems that there is null pointer exception. you may be getting null value for action bar.. try getActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

I have found the solution. This worked:

```
 ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
```